# Question on non-diagonal metric tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

Can a non-diagonal metric tensor be used to raise and lower indices? I am asking this because it turns out that the metric tensor need not always be diagonal. As such, I’m not sure if it’s true that the metric tensor by definition, can be used to raise and/or lower indices, even though it’s not diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), vectors' indices move viz. $v_\mu=g_{\mu\nu}v^\nu,\,v^\nu=g^{\nu\rho}v_\rho$ (this generalizes to other tensors). So$$\delta_\mu^\rho v_\rho=v_\mu=g_{\mu\nu}g^{\nu\rho}v_\rho\implies g_{\mu\nu}g^{\nu\rho}=\delta_\mu^\rho.$$In other words, the two tensors are just each other's inverses as matrices, whether they're diagonal or not. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington%E2%80%93Finkelstein_coordinates#Metric) are [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantum_gravity#Canonical_quantization_in_metric_variables) important examples of non-diagonal metrics.

Comment: But consider the definition of the line element $g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu} \mathrm{d}x^{\nu}= \mathrm{d}x_{\mu} \mathrm{d}x^{\mu}$. If the metric tensor is non diagonal then the LHS gives off diagonal terms while the RHS gives only diagonal terms. How does one reconcile this notational issue?

Comment: @Thomas: because you're hiding "off diagonal" terms in the definition of $dx_{\mu}$.  If the metric is non-diagonal, the raising and lowering operations mix bases.

Comment: Is it then correct to say that the RHS is merely a notational representation of the calculation of the LHS and does not actually represent the definition of $x^\mu$?

Comment: @Thomas $\mathrm{d}s^2=\mathrm{d}x_\mu\mathrm{d}x^\mu$ no more proves the metric tensor is diagonal than that it's the identity.

Comment: I see. Does that mean then that what I said above about notational representation is true?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the metric tensor is always used to raise and lower indices. The components (whether they are diagonal or not) depend on the choice of coordinate system, but the tensors themselves do not. For example, if we want to lower the index of a vector, the operation is written in coordinate-free form as
$$g(v)$$
which can be expressed equivalently in components as
$$g_{ij} \mathbf{e}^i \otimes \mathbf{e}^j (v^k \mathbf{e}_k) = g_{ij} v^k \mathbf{e}^i \delta^j_k = (g_{ij} v^j) \mathbf{e}^i$$
and this must hold in all coordinate systems.

Answer (score 0):

A bilinear form $\Omega:V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb R$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ provides an [isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) between $V$ and its algebraic dual space $V^*$ if and only if it is [non-degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_bilinear_form), which operationally means that the matrix $\Omega_{ij}$ of its components (in any basis) is invertible.

If this condition holds, then we define the maps $\flat:V\rightarrow V^*$ and $\sharp:V^*\rightarrow V$ via

$$(X^\flat)_i = \Omega_{ij} X^j$$
$$(\omega^\sharp)^i = (\Omega^{-1})^{ij} \omega_j$$

The standard convention is that the symbols $\flat$ and $\sharp$ are suppressed, with the distinction between e.g. the components of $X$ and $X^\flat$ to be understood purely based on the placement of the index.  Similarly, we just write $(\Omega^{-1})^{ij} \equiv \Omega^{ij}$.

---

A Lorentzian metric is non-degenerate *by definition*, thereby satisfying this requirement.  Indeed, whether the metric is diagonal or not is a purely basis-dependent question, and in principle we can always choose a basis which diagonalizes the metric - see e.g. [the tetrad formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_formalism).